# How to increase the Service address range of a GKE cluster

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, gke-networking

One of my GKE clusters is running out of IPs for Services. It was originally created with the default service address range (10.0.0.0/20), and we are about to hit the 4k services mark.

Is there a way to expand the service address range of an existing GKE cluster? The cluster's subnet has enough space to allocate more IPs, but I haven't found an API or command to change it.

https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/alias-ips#cluster_sizing_secondary_range_svcs mentions that editing the secondary range is not possible while it's in use.  Is there a way to replace it, and let GKE roll the IPs of the services?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Unfortunately, there is no possibility to change the `IP service range` after the cluster was created in a `GKE` cluster.**

There is a message in creation process of `GKE` cluster:

[image: Service address range GKE]

As you can see this setting is **permanent**.

The official documentation that you linked points:

> Because this is also a subnet secondary IP range, **you can only replace it when no Google Cloud resources use it**. This range cannot be changed as long as a cluster uses it for Services (cluster IP addresses).
>
> --  *[Cloud.google.com: Kubernetes Engine: Cluster sizing secondary range svcs](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/alias-ips#cluster_sizing_secondary_range_svcs)*

It is actively used by your `GKE` cluster. Even if you try to go associated VPC  to change it will be greyed out as shown below:

[image: VPC network]

Please let me know if you have any questions in that.

Comment: Sad indeed, we ended up having to migrate our cluster to one with a bigger subnetwork.